# Find base coordinates for oblique pyramid with rectangular base with known apex coordinates, unit direction vectors and base side lengths

Tags: geometry

Given an oblique pyramid with a rectangular base and the following **known** parameters:

- apex coordinates $X$
- the **unit** direction vectors $\hat{XA},\hat{XB},\hat{XC},\hat{XD}$, which go from $X$ in the direction of the four base points $A,B,C,D$
- the length of the four base sides (i.e. $\rvert \vec{AB} \lvert,\rvert \vec{CB} \lvert,\rvert \vec{DC} \lvert,\rvert \vec{DA} \lvert$)

Is it possible to find a unique solution for the four base coordinates $A,B,C,D$ ?

See the following image for an illustration of the initial situation. Known parameters are colored in blue, while missing base coordinates are red.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = |X-A|$, and similarly for $b,c,d$. These are the four unknowns.
You know that $A=X + a X_A$ (where $X_A$ is that unit vector)
and $B= X + b X_B$, and $|A-B|^2 = {AB}^2$.
This yields four quadratic equations in the four unknowns.
This permits you to find all solutions. Whether there will always be just one
solution, I don't know.